# "un mur de pierres" "un mur de pierre" "un mur en pierre"

Tags: prépositions, différence, noun-phrases

Duolingo marked "Elle fait un mur de pierre" wrong, demanding "Elle fait un mur de **pierres**". But then the following sentence had "un mur en pierre". I'm pretty familiar and comfortable with the "noun + en + singular" construction to describe something in/made of a certain material, but why doesn't a noun in the singular work in "noun de noun"? Google seems to show tons of hits for ["mur de pierre"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22mur%20de%20pierre%22)

Also how are "un mur de pierre(s)" and "un mur en pierre" different? I have read these discussions ([1](https://languefrancaise.net/forum/viewtopic.php?id=8140), [2](https://www.achyra.org/francais/viewtopic.php?t=3075)) but I'm still not clear on the difference.

Comment: No difference, all 3 are correct and in use.

Comment: FWIW, I'm a native French speaker and I remember not always agreeing with Duolingo's French translations in the *Spanish for French speakers* course. I got marked down a bunch of times where it rejected a correct alternative 
or insisted on an awkward literal translation.

Comment: @DamienD I totally agree with your assessment. Duolingo lacks consistency in that aspect. Recently I have seen a lot of translation questions where the English version sounded awkward, unnatural, or even ungrammatical, supposedly as a result of Duolingo demanding a literal, word-for-word translation. But I think at earlier stages Duolingo seems to provide English sentences in idiomatic American English. I even remember thinking "oh a Brit might get confused by some of these prepositions here"

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from the *Banque de dépannage linguistique* : [Les prépositions introduisant une matière](https://vitrinelinguistique.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/22167/la-syntaxe/les-prepositions/preposition-devant-un-nom/les-prepositions-introduisant-une-matiere):

> Les prépositions *de* et *en* permettent toutes les deux d’introduire un complément de matière. L’emploi de *en* était autrefois critiqué, mais il est maintenant passé dans l’usage courant.

So, both *un mur de pierre* et *un mur en pierre* are both fine nowadays. It is also perfectly fine to have *pierre* in the singular or in the plural here.  The singular referring to the substance in itself, the plural referring to the  substance being divided into fragments.  So *un mur en pierres* and *un mur de pierres* are also fine.

But we would not use the plural with any sort of substance. I would find weird to write *une bague en ors*, even though the ring would be made of white, yellow and pink gold. A little less  weird to write *une robe en/de tissus*, the use of the plural indicates straight away that the dress is not made of one single material. With *tissu/s*,  both *en* and *de* are used but I would think that *en* is more frequent, but *de* is not wrong.

Un *mur en béton*, *un mur de béton* are both used, but I don't expect *béton* would be used in the plural in this case, even if there are different kinds of concrete. I expect the use of the plural in the case of describing the material being used much depends on what the eye can perceive at fist sight.

Comment: I think the plural is ok when the word doubles as a physical countable object. *Une pierre* can be visualised instantly. *Or, béton, tissu* are not countable as physical objects, they're only countable as categories. Eg you can have two stones of the same stone but it makes no sense to speak of two fabrics of the same fabric, you'd need to say "two pieces of".